# Default access modifier for new C#-classes in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio, access-modifiers

When I generate a new class in Visual Studio (C#), I would like to have the default access modifier changed from "internal" to "public". E.g.:

```cs
public class Animal
{
}
```

instead of:

```cs
internal class Animal
{
}
```

Is there a setting in Visual Studio (2022) where the default access modifier for new classes can be set?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-item-templates?view=vs-2022

Comment: I really hate the fact that MS made that change. Cost me so much time. Why would I make a class internal when other projects need it, which is sooooo common.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can change it at

> %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class

Comment: i tried that but no effect, it seems its using template from different location

Comment: I can't believe that internal is set as default and the fact that they don't have the option to remove it, that you have to navigate to this directory and modify the template manually is ridiculous in paid software of this caliber. This worked for me. Thanks!

Comment: worked for me. but I agree with @dh6984

Answer (score 42):

I tried same for Visual Studio Community 2022 (V 17.1.0)

Open `Class.cs`  at

> %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\CSharp\Code\1033\Class\Class.cs

The *Class.cs*  file location depends on your installation directory.

Existing class code

```
class $safeitemrootname$
{
}
```

Add `public` keyword

```
public class $safeitemrootname$
{
}
```

and Save the file. It's working on my machine.

Comment: Man this is so weird.  I can't find my 2022 installation folder.  It only shows 2017 and 2019.  Yes, I did install 2022 and I am working in it.

Comment: what is the location of installation? check it thru visual studio installer, you will see 2022 folder there...

Comment: Solution works, you might need to pay attention to also what kind of visual studio you have (Community/Professional/etc..)

Comment: @Sam And to anyone else having an issue finding the directory, it's not located in Program Files (x86). It will be in Program Files; if you have not changed default directory upon installation, that is.

Answer (score 6):

Rohit's answer worked for me in VS2022 v17.2.3.

If you face 'Access to the path is denied' message when saving Class.cs, do this:

- Copy the file Class.cs to a different folder (your desktop, for instance)
- Edit Class.cs file on the new folder and save it
- Move Class.cs itself to it's original folder (...\CSharp\Code\1033\Class)
- Windows will ask for administrator permissions to override the file, click 'Continue'
- Close and reopen VS before creating a new class to be sure

Comment: It worked for me too. Do not try to rename within the ...\CSharp\Code\1033\Class. Move the file, make the change and move it back.